# Is it possible to create a webapp that securely connects to a user specified database?

Tags: database, mongodb, security, web-applications

I am designing a research application and we want all research data to reside with the user.

One idea is to somehow allow users to connect to their own database (not sure how...) which we can read/write. Is this possible to achieve securely? MongoDB will likely be our db of choice.

Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you rather propose to your clients to deploy your website/webapp to their servers, then it will be connected to their hosted database and will 100% securely used only by them.